# No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf when running jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

when I started jupyter notebook, I saw the warnings:

```
    Unrecognized JSON config file version, assuming version 1
    ✗ nbpresent PDF export DISABLED: No module named nbbrowserpdf.exporters.pdf
```

And then it got stuck there.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I found the answer to it:

```
    conda install -c anaconda-nb-extensions nbbrowserpdf
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
conda config --add channels conda-forge

conda install nbbrowserpdf
```

Reference: https://github.com/conda-forge/nbbrowserpdf-feedstock